# Как определить оператор * с симметрией по отношению к его параметрам?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Нужно определить оператор * для класса CardDeck.

```
CardDeck& operator*(const CardDeck&, const int);
```

Естественно, реализация оператора происходит с помощью инициализации нового Дэка переданным и с помощью цикла повторяется += необходимое количество раз.
Есть ли в данном случае способ сказать компилятору, что последовательность параметров не имеет значения, то есть любую последовательность нужных параметров пусть подгоняет под одну функцию, чтобы не писать вторую с обратным порядком параметров, которая будет вызывать первую перевернув порядок?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Может лучше объясните, какого эффекта вы хотите добиться, кодом.

Comment: И так. Есть класс "Дэк", нужно загрузить оператор "*" для двух элементов этого класса. Допустим что у нас уже реализованный оператор += для данного класса. Поэтому переданный параметр (refference) Дэка мы с помощью оператора = загрузим в новый "дэк" и по отношению к этому объекту используем += необходимое количество раз. Вопрос состоял в том, можно ли сказать компилятору игнорировать порядок передаваемх параметров.
Ниже толково ответили.

Comment: А, теперь понятно, что вы подразумевали под «игнорировать порядок».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, надо определять оба оператора.
Однако один можно определить через другой.

```
CardDeck& operator*(const CardDeck& lhs, int rhs);
inline CardDeck& operator*(int lhs, const CardDeck& rhs) { return rhs * lhs; }
```

Comment: Благодарю. А выше непонятно описано ? Я уже подумал, что это я недостаточно ясно описал, но вроде для понимающих понятно. 

То есть в языке это самыйоптимальный вариант, сказать компилятору каким-то префиксом или суфиксом "подгоняй под нужный порядок" невозможно, да ?

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, данное объявление оператора

```
CardDeck& operator*(const CardDeck&, const int);
```

некорректное. Очевидно, что происходит возврат ссылки на локальный объект функции или отбрасывание квалификатора `const` у первого параметра переданного по ссылке.

В любом случае это ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Кроме того совершенно нет никакой необходимости указывать квалификатор `const` для второго параметра, так как для него аргумент передается по значению, то есть используется копия аргумента.

Написание оператора зависит от того, есть ли функции преобразования из объекта типа `int` в объект типа `CardDeck` или из объекта `CardDeck`  в объект типа `int`. Так как наличие таких функций может избавить вас от написания двух операторов, либо же может привести к неоднозначности выбора оператора.

Если таких функций нет, то вам придется писать два оператора.

Их объявления могут выглядеть следующим образом

```
CardDeck operator *( const CardDeck &, int );
CardDeck operator *( int, const CardDeck & );
```

Причем один из операторов можно определить через второй оператор, просто поменяв местами аргументы. Например,

```
CardDeck operator *( int value, const CardDeck &deck ) { return deck * value; }
```

Кроме того возможно вам также имеет смысл объявить операторы для `rvalue` объекта `CardDeck`, как, например,

```
CardDeck operator *( CardDeck &&, int );
CardDeck operator *( int, CardDeck && );
```

Comment: согласен с замечаниями, кроме главного. В функции новый объект будет загруенным на хип, поэтому возвращая референс на него, все с ним будет ок. Ключевой момент вы не поняли, мне здесь не нужен преобразователь, подумайте над оператором "умножить" для любого класса. Показатель типа int определяет сколько раз мне нужно суммировать, в независимости от класса. В остальном благодарю.

Comment: @Ilya.K. Даже если вы создаете объект в динамической памяти, определение оператора некорректное, так как из определения никто за удаление объекта не отвечает. Это ведет к утечке памяти.

Comment: да, точно, здесь также как и с оператором сложения, нужно вернуть by_value, а создание и уничтожение объекта в динамическом памяти контролировать вручную в нужном месте, 100%